# MySQL DATABASE - SQL statement to join join two tables using a third table

Tags: mysql, database

I am a little confused with this question. it asks for the following:  "Create a single SQL statement that will display all columns from the student and professor tables. You will need to use the student_professor table to set up the joins."

Normally this wouldnt be difficult under the circumstances of just having 2 tables using a related column, but this is asking me to use a 3rd table?

These are the tables

`professor`, `student`, `student_professor`

Columns for 'professor'

`ProfessorId`, `ProfessorProgram`, `PhoneNo`, `Age`, `ProfessorName`

Columns for 'student'

`studentno`, `studentprogram`, `phoneno`, `age`, `firstname`, `lastname`

Columns for 'student_professor'

`student_professor_id`, `ProfessorId`, `StudentNo`, `Mentor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but this should get you started:

```
SELECT s.*, p.*
FROM professor p, student s, student_professor sp
WHERE sp.professorId = p.proffesorId
AND   sp.studentNo = s.studentNo
ORDER BY p.ProfessorName, s.lastname, s.firstname
```

or

```
SELECT s.*, p.*
FROM professor p
JOIN student_professor sp ON sp.professorId = p.proffesorId
JOIN student s ON sp.studentNo = s.studentNo
ORDER BY p.ProfessorName, s.lastname, s.firstname
```

Comment: Recommend sticking to the second `JOIN` syntax. It makes it harder to miss the join criteria, especially as queries get bigger.